# How to slice a list using indexes in another list

Tags: python, list, slice

I start with a long list, long let's say 4438. I need to create a list of sublists of that starting list. To do that, I have a list of indexes:

```
indexes = [0, 888, 1776, 2664, 3551, 4438]
```

This means, in my final list, the first sublist takes the first 888 elements, the second one the following 888, the third one the following 888 and so on.

What I need is the sublists to be:

```
sublist_1 = list_to_slice[0:888]
sublist_2 = list_to_slice[888:1776]
sublist_3 = list_to_slice[1776:2664]
...
```

My code:

```
final_list = [list_to_slice[i:i+1] for i in indexes]
```

The problem with my code is that instead of doing the above slicing, it does:

```
sublist_1 = list_to_slice[0:1]
sublist_2 = list_to_slice[888:889]
sublist_3 = list_to_slice[1776:1777]
...
```

That `i+1` is deemed 'add 1 to the index i' instead of 'take the index that follows i', how can I get the code to do the latter? I need a fine piece of code that does this kind of slicing, I don't care if different to mine.

Comment: Iterate the list in blocks. For example: `[indexes[i:i+10] for i in indexes[::10]]`.

Comment: You could change your code so that it will use `indexes[i]` and `indexes[i+1]` instead of `i` and `i+1`. Of course, this requires to generate `i` differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.pairwise`:

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise
>>> for i, j in pairwise([0, 888, 1776, 2664, 3551, 4438]):
...     print(i, j)
...
0 888
888 1776
1776 2664
2664 3551
3551 4438
```

What's next? I think you can solve it yourself.

Comment: As a side note, `pairwise` has been introduced in 3.10